# Expo EAS build failing when compiling Expo (Expo Managed app)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to compile my React Native app built using Expo (Expo managed workflow), and it keeps failing with this error

```
> Task :expo-application:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (15, 21): Unresolved reference: core
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (16, 21): Unresolved reference: core
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (17, 21): Unresolved reference: core
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (18, 21): Unresolved reference: core
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (19, 21): Unresolved reference: core
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (20, 21): Unresolved reference: core
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (27, 58): Unresolved reference: ExportedModule
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (27, 84): Unresolved reference: RegistryLifecycleListener
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (28, 32): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistry
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (29, 34): Unresolved reference: ActivityProvider
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (32, 3): 'getName' overrides nothing
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (36, 3): 'onCreate' overrides nothing
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (36, 41): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistry
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (38, 50): Unresolved reference: ActivityProvider
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (42, 3): 'getConstants' overrides nothing
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (65, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoMethod
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (66, 41): Unresolved reference: Promise
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (78, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoMethod
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (79, 39): Unresolved reference: Promise
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (91, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoMethod
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationModule.kt: (92, 40): Unresolved reference: Promise
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationPackage.kt: (4, 21): Unresolved reference: core
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationPackage.kt: (5, 21): Unresolved reference: core
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationPackage.kt: (7, 28): Unresolved reference: BasePackage
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationPackage.kt: (8, 3): 'createExportedModules' overrides nothing
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationPackage.kt: (8, 62): Unresolved reference: ExportedModule
[stderr] e: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/application/ApplicationPackage.kt: (9, 49): Unresolved reference: ExportedModule
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':expo-application:compileReleaseKotlin'.
[stderr] > Compilation error. See log for more details
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 3m 44s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
204 actionable tasks: 204 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "igas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.1.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-camera": "^12.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-scroll-lazy": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-side-menu-updated": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.14.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Tried updating all packages (project was previously on Expo SDK 42, updated to SDK 44).
When running expo upgrade some packages didn't update, so I had to do it by hand.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have almost the same problem but with `expo-images-picker`

Comment: @laneboyandrew sadly I never fixed the issue, but I simply went back to the regular build process `expo build:android` or `expo build:ios`. I'm thinking this is just some bug that will be fixed, since EAS is still an early thing imo. Not a permanent fix of course, since it will be deprecated by next year if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: this is a question at expo forum. Maybe you will find it useful https://forums.expo.dev/t/imagepicker-expo-sdk-44-and-eas-build-trhows-error-on-gradlew-build-unresolved-reference-ifnull/60206

Comment: what if you add `expo-application` dependency to `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check

> Custom "main" entry point in package.json is not yet supported

From this article

https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/